# In how many ways can four squares, not all in the same row or column, be selected from an $8 \times 8$ chessboard to form a rectangle?

Tags: combinatorics

I know this involves creating a combinatorial argument but this problem is really complex.

Answer (score 3):

For rectangles with sides parallel to the sides of the board, you just have to select two rows out of eight and two columns out of eight.  Are you counting oblique rectangles, too?

Comment: No oblique rectangles will not count

Comment: Then you have $8\cdot 7/2$ ways to choose the columns, and the same for the rows, making $28^2=824$

Comment: I'm guessing you meant 28^2 = 784

Comment: @user61646:  yes.